# Convert Content Type Text/HTML to JSON from API

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to pull data from GetBible.net API https://getbible.net/api.  When you view the headers the content type is `text/html`.  I'd like to turn it into a JSON.

I've tried everything on StackOverflow to include encoding, decoding, parsing it, un-gzipping it and nothing works.

```
import requests
import json

def bible_app():
    response = requests.get("http://getbible.net/json?passage=Jn3:16").json()
    print(response)

bible_app()
```

Error no matter what I do:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, contrary to what the documentation says, the response returned by that URL is not valid JSON. According to [this issue](https://github.com/getbible/Joomla-3-Component/issues/14) you should append `&raw=true` to the URL in order to get a proper JSON response:

```
response = requests.get("http://getbible.net/json?passage=Jn3:16&raw=true").json()
```

Comment: No, this argument is specific to that site's implementation (and I found it highly confusing). Normally APIs return valid JSON by default.

Comment: so it worked but the first key is "book" and the value is a giant list "[{'book_ref': 'Jn', 'book_name': 'John', 'book_nr': '43', 'chapter_nr': '3', 'chapter': {'16': {'verse_nr': '16', 'verse': 'For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.\r\n'}}}]"  Is there a way to change this to a dict to just pull the 'verse'?

Comment: I guess the reason is that there _might be_ multiple books. Just use `response["book"][0]` if you are only interested in the first element.